# Python ctypes and dynamic linking

Tags: python, ctypes, dynamic-linking

I'm writing some libraries in C which contain functions that I want to call from Python via ctypes.

I've done this successfully another library, but that library had only very vanilla dependencies (namely `fstream`, `math`, `malloc`, `stdio`, `stdlib`). The other library I'm working on has more complicated dependencies.

For example, I'll try to use `fftw3`. As a test, I'll just try to compile a simple `.cpp` file containing:

```
int foo()
{
    void *p  = fftw_malloc( sizeof(fftw_complex)*64 );
    fftw_free(p);

    printf("foo called.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it as:

```
icpc -Wall -fPIC -c waveprop.cpp -o libwaveprop.o $std_link
icpc -shared -Wl,-soname,libwaveprop.so.1 -o libwaveprop.so.1.0 libwaveprop.o 

cp waveprop.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/
rm waveprop.so.1.0
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so.1
```

This all works. Now I test it with another `.cpp` file containing:

```
int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

Result:

```
icpc test.cpp -lwaveprop 
/lib/../lib64/libwaveprop.so: undefined reference to `fftw_free'
/lib/../lib64/libwaveprop.so: undefined reference to `fftw_malloc'
```

Which is entirely reasonable. Next I try:

```
icpc test.cpp -lwaveprop -lfftw3
./a.out
foo called.
```

Great! But now when I try to load the library with ctypes:

```
>>> from ctypes import *
>>> print cdll.LoadLibrary('/usr/local/lib/libwaveprop.so.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 431, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/ctypes/__init__.py", line 353, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /usr/local/lib/libwaveprop.so.1: undefined symbol: fftw_free
```

So it's the same problem, but I have no idea how to resolve it for ctypes. I've tried various things without any success, and I'm pretty stuck at this point.

Answer (score 4):

OK, thanks for your help.

to get this to work I had to include the dependencies when linking (duh). I had tried this before but got an error, so solve this I had to recompile fftw with '-fpic' as a CPP flag. all works now.

```
icpc -Wall -fPIC -c waveprop.cpp -o libwaveprop.o $std_link
icpc -shared -Wl,-soname,libwaveprop.so.1 -o libwaveprop.so.1.0 libwaveprop.o -lfftw3

cp waveprop.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/
rm waveprop.so.1.0
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so
ln -sf /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so.1.0 /usr/local/lib/waveprop.so.1
```

thanks,
-nick

Answer (score 0):

You need to link `libwaveprop.so` itself against the fftw3 library. Otherwise Python simply won't know where to go to get those missing symbols; mind-reading isn't implemented in any programming language.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

That's one of the things I tried.

    icpc -shared -Wl,-soname,libwaveprop.so.1 -o libwaveprop.so.1.0 libwaveprop.o -lfftw3

and

    icpc -shared -Wl,-soname,libwaveprop.so.1 -o libwaveprop.so.1.0 libwaveprop.o 

both give the same error:

    ld: /usr/local/lib/libfftw3.a(malloc.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `fftw_kernel_malloc' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
    ld: final link failed: Bad value

I'm not sure what to do with that. Any ideas?

thanks,
-nick

Comment: Well, “compile to `.o` with `-fPIC` and link to `.so` against the libraries that you depend on” is the technique that I've learned. Can't diagnose what's wrong without further info, sorry.